# Will unplucked pikmin be left behind at the end of a day?

Tags: pikmin

In Pikmin 1, if I have Pikmin sprouts I haven't plucked yet, what happens to the unplucked Pikmin when a day ends? Will they be left behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pikmin that have been left in the ground will remain there and will have bloomed into Flower Pikmin by the next day.

I do not know if there are any limitations to this system, such as a maximum number of Pikmin that are carried over, a maximum number of days they may remain in the ground, or whether visiting another location will remove them.